# What is the equation of the tangent drawn to the function $f(x)$ at the point $ x = 1 $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line

Here is question and my attempts: I can not get the correct answer.

> Let
>   $$f(x)=\int_x^{x^2}\frac{2t^2+1}{t^3+2}dt$$
>   What is the equation of the tangent drawn to the function $f(x)$ at the point $ x = 1 $?
>
> *A)* $y=-x$
>
> *B)* $y=x$
>
> *C)* $y=2x$
>
> *D)* $y=\frac x2$
>
> *E)* $y=\frac{3x}2$

My attempt:
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\int_x^{x^2}\frac{2t^2+1}{t^3+2}dt\\
y&=f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)\\
f(1)&=\int_1^{1}\frac{2t^2+1}{t^3+2}dt=0\\
f'(x)&=\frac{2x^4+1}{x^6+2}\cdot2x-\frac{2x^2+1}{x^3+2}\cdot1\\
f'(1)&=\frac33\cdot2-\frac33\cdot1=1\\
y&=x-1
\end{align}

Comment: @vrugtehagel Thank you very much..

Comment: I got to $$f (x)=\frac 29 \int_{x^3+2}^{x^6+2}{u^{-2}(u-2)^{-\frac 23}du} $$ Don't know if it's useful but perhaps worth a try.

Comment: The right answer is not part of the options; for one, the tangent should pass through $(1,f(1))$ (and indeed $f(1)=0$, so it should pass through $(1,0)$) but none of the options pass through $(1,0)$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel I understood..Well, is my solution correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is totally fine. Except for a lack of words I have nothing to say about it. Your textbook is incorrect, as the correct answer is not part of the options.

Answer (score 1):

As you notice, none of the given answers satisfy $f(1)=0$ which is required.

I have checked your work and your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The proposed answers are all incorrect because $f(1)=0$ and any line $y=mx$ with $ m\not=0$ gives $y(1)=m\not=0$.

Note that the tangent to the graph of $f$ at $x_0=0$ is
$$y=f(0)+f'(0)x=-\frac{x}{2}.$$
So even for such point all answers are wrong.